# Using Terrain Profile plugin with an interpolated raster

Tags: qgis, raster, qgis-plugins, interpolation, terrain

I am very new to QGIS and the goal of this exercise is to view an elevation profile of a river from a set of discrete points taken from surveying records.

Steps taken:

1. A vector layer was created from a delimited text layer (exported
   from excel)
2. An .asc file was created using the interpolation plugin
3. The .asc file was converted to a raster .tif using the translate
           tool
4. Attempted to use the terrain profile plugin

I tried using a temporary polyline, but each time the plot showed up empty

**Updates:**

I got the following Python error when I tried adding my raster elevation layer to the Terrain Profile tool

[image: Python Error]

@Bernd V. - I tried using a normal polyline, and still now success - see image below:

[image: Empty elevation profile 2]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].  Offering to email data is not something that should be included in your question, which should be self-contained.

Comment: Did you also try: - to use not a temporary, but a normal polyline? - to start and end the line within the data range of your raster? It seems like you start the line in a NODATA area.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem that frustrated me for a long time but I've finally found the solution. It is very important that you follow the following steps when generating a profile:

1) Select the relevant DEM layer in the layers panel

2) Select Plugins/Profile Tool/ Terrain Profile

3) Select the polyline layer that you want to use for the profile in the layers panel

4) Select Selection=Selected Polyline

**5) Click the green Terrain Profile Plugin Button (the cursor is shown on the button in the attached screenshot)**

6) Then select the polyline

The profile will then be generated. **It is REALLY IMPORTANT that you click the Terrain Profile Plugin Button immediately before selecting the polyline**. If you don't do this the profile won't be generated.

You may have another problem but this worked for me.

Hope this helps,

Ben